# How to sleep before retrying in struts action?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a use case where my struts action reads file from file system and then returns it in server response. I want to add retry logic where my request sleeps for some time before retrying to read the file, what is the best way to achieve that?

I want to retry for 10 times after waiting 1 second between each retries. I found Thread.sleep(1000) which puts the current thread on sleep. Is this the correct way?

```java
public String execute()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Read the file system
        if (break_condition) {
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to use `Thread.sleep` in a server context as it might have unwanted implications.

The proposed approach would be different depending on the server and frameworks that are available. The core of the idea is however that you use the specific API for scheduling, or doing (retrying) something in a future that your server provides and avoid using the `Thread.sleep()`.

The key difference is that the thread will not sleep and remain idle before proceeding further. The thread will notify the server to do something after a specific duration and then the thread will continue working.

If you are in Java-EE environment the be [TimerService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) would be a good idea.It can be implemented with `TimerService.createSingleActionTimer()`.

For example, if you are in a Jave EE server you can do the following:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;

@Stateless
public class RetryWithWaitBean {


   @Resource
   private SessionContext context;

    /**
    *Create a timer that will be activated after the duration passes.
    */
   public void doActionAfterDuration(long durationMillis) {
      final TimerConfig timerConfig= new TimerConfig()
      timerConfig.setPersistent(false);
      context.getTimerService()..createSingleActionTimer(durationMillis,timerConfig);
   }

   /** Automatically executed by server on timer expiration.
   */
   @Timeout
   public void timeout(Timer timer) {
      System.out.println("Trying after timeout. Timer: " + timer.getInfo()); 
      //Do custom action 
      doAction();

      timer.cancel();
   }

   /**
    * Doing the required action 
    */
   private void doAction(){
      //add your logic here. This code will run after your timer.
    System.out.println("Action DONE!"); 
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like that:

```
 //This code should be in a managed context so that the server injects it.
 @EJB 
 private RetryWithWaitBean retryWithWaitBean ;
```

Then you can use it like that.

```
//do an action after 3000 milliseconds
retryWithWaitBean.doActionAfterDuration(3000);
```

There are many ways to achieve similar results depending on the framework you use.

Comment: Ca you edit your example with some code so that I can understand how does this solves my use case? I want to block my server request until all the retries are complete